# IWebHistBuilder.ConfigureLogging AddFilter for Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a web API which also implements an alive check.
When debugging on the server side, all calls to the API are logged to a console.
As the alive check is called every second it's logged message is spamming the console.
I would like to exclude that single method from being logged.

What I've tried so far:

```
...
webBuilder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                            {
                                logging.ClearProviders();
                                logging.AddConsole();
                                logging.AddFilter(LogLevel.Warning);
                            });
```

This suppresses all methods from being logged.

I tried to add Attributes to the method:

```
[HttpGet, Route("AliveCheck"), Category("DoNotLog")]
public RequestReply AliveCheck()
{
    return RequestReply.Ok;
}
```

and tried to filter it with:

```
...
Func<string,  LogLevel, bool> filter = delegate (string category, LogLevel logLevel)
{
    return category == "DoNotLog";
};

webBuilder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                            {
                                logging.ClearProviders();
                                logging.AddConsole();
                                logging.AddFilter(filter);
                            });
```

which did not work. I can never see that Category appear...
(Propably as the Category attribute is not for AspNetCore).

Also I tried to add a LoggerMessage attribute to the AliveCheck method with Level = LogLevel.Trace:

```
[HttpGet, Route("AliveCheck"), LoggerMessage(Level = LogLevel.Trace)]
public RequestReply AliveCheck()
{
    return RequestReply.Ok;
}
```

This did not have any effect either.

Is it possible to achieve, what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use middleware. Filtering urls can be done with middleware, and the code is the least, and it does not affect your existing functions.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // add your logic here
    if (context.Request.Path != "/AliveCheck")
    {
        logger.LogInformation("HTTP request: {Path}", context.Request.Path);
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```